# Install PECL v8js on Debian Jessy

Tags: php, debian

I try to install pecl-v8js on Debian/Jessy for PHP-5.6.

```
$ apt-get install php5 php5-dev libapache2-mod-php5 apache2 php5-cli libv8-dev g++ cpp
...
$ pecl install v8js-0.6.3
    ...
    checking for V8 version... 3.14.5.8
    configure: error: libv8 must be version 4.6.76 or greater
    ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/v8js/configure --with-v8js' failed
```

How can i upgrade libv8 to the required 4.6.76 ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to build from source.  Even Debian unstable still has 3.14.5.8 packaged.

Comment: Where can I find the sources?

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.  Also, if you can't work out how to find the libv8 source, you *probably* shouldn't try building it.